# Fail to load Mesh with STL on Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, sdf, ignition-fortress, stl

I try to load my robot sdf file. But Gazebo cannot load my stl mesh and give these errors

```
[Err] [SystemPaths.cc:378] Unable to find file with URI [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[Err] [SystemPaths.cc:473] Could not resolve file [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[Err] [MeshManager.cc:173] Unable to find file[model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [SystemPaths.cc:378] Unable to find file with URI [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [SystemPaths.cc:473] Could not resolve file [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [MeshManager.cc:173] Unable to find file[model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [MeshDescriptor.cc:56] Mesh manager can't find mesh named [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:562] Cannot load null mesh [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:125] Failed to get Ogre item for [model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL]
[GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:404] Failed to load geometry for visual: link1_visual
```

I can load it up on Gazebo Fortress, but it cannot be visually seen. Here is my sdf file:

```
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='hexapod'>
    <link name='link1'>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.334167</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.334167</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.00166667</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='link1_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='link1_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>model://hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Does anyone know why gazebo cannot load my STL file? I export it from Solidwork file and it works fine in RVIZ

UPDATE: I moved my STL file into the same folder with my SDF file. I now load without any error but still being invisible. Does anyone know what cause it?
Here is my new sdf file:

```
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='hexapod'>
    <link name='link1'>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 1 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.334167</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.334167</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.00166667</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='link1_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>link1.STL</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <contact>
            <ode/>
          </contact>
          <friction>
            <ode/>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name='link1_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>link1.STL</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <name>Gazebo/Orange</name>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

SOLVED: I made a mistake in my IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. Here is my correct one:
export IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH="$HOME/uchi/hexapod_ws/"
If you think your path is correct, make sure to source your workspace before running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first problem:
I think you just have to delete `model://` to be able to find your stl file:

```
<mesh>
  <scale>1 1 1</scale>
  <uri>hexapod_description/mesh/link1.STL</uri>
</mesh>
```

About your second problem with the invisibility:
Are your sure your model is invisible? Maybe it's a scaling problem and your imported model is just very small or very large. I faced the same problem while converting some meshes and it turned out there was a problem between US and EU decimal sepearation, so that my model was scaled up about 1000x and I had to zoom out very far to see it.

Comment: 1st problem: if I remove model:// or package:// the directory is always pointing into the folder where I store my sdf file. It would be inconvenient to organize my files and folders. That's why I try to use model:// or package://. Because I use Fortress, I source my IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH, but it doesn't work and also it would cause another problem that if I run my model on different device, I have to manually set up the path again.
For 2nd problem, yes, my gazebo misunderstood my unit in STL, so it became so huge and out of my screen. But only when it is in same folder with my sdf file

Comment: For 2nd problem, you have any solution to make the whole robot scale down but still being attached to each other parts. I try to use <scale> but it only scale individual parts and the joints don't keep up with the scale, making parts visually being detached

Comment: 1st Problem: I never tried loading models via a environment variable, but according to the ignition documentation, gazebo is first looking in the local directory and then in the paths given in IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. Could you check your content of IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH with env and post is here? Maybe the path format is invalid.  
2nd problem: Which tool have you used for the conversion to stl? There should also be a possibility to scale your model either alongside your converstion process to stl or in a seperate step after the conversion.

Comment: 1st problem: I made a mistake when sourcing my IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. I figured it out and now it works fine.
2nd problem: I used Soliworks to get my STL files. But my problem is that my student version is expired and I'm graduated. My school doesn't let me extend my free student version. Now I have no access into my solidworks file to change my model units. Do you know any CAD could be able to read STL and do unit conversion?

Comment: Sure, you could use MeshLab. It's open source